# "Warp" to a view iPhone iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, logout

I am currently developing an App based on a Navigation Controller. However, when the user logs out, I'd like to go to the initial screen and destroy all of the other views that were stacked. What is the best way to do that?

EDIT:

I've tried doing what both answers suggested but I got a `nil` `navigationViewController`. So I'll add another detail that I thought was not useful before. Actually I am trying to perform this operation from a TabViewController that is embedded in a NavigationController. I apologize if that changes anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: This sounds like a bad view controller setup but does self.tabBarController.navigationController return something that is not nil?

Comment: I was actually doing one thing wrong: I was calling dismiss on a modal before calling the above method. Inverting the order made it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Send a popToRootViewControllerAnimated message to the navigation controller